# Declaring one, two, many arguments in Scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, variadic-functions

I'm just starting to learn Scala. While browsing through the Scaladocs I saw this method definition in [`mutable.Map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Map):

```
def -=(elem1: A, elem2: A, elems: A*): Map.this.type
  Removes two or more elements from this shrinkable collection.

  elem1 the first element to remove.
  elem2 the second element to remove.
  elems the remaining elements to remove.
  returns the shrinkable collection itself
```

Why would you need to define `elem1` and `elem2` explicitly if you're just going to define `elems` with a `*` anyway?

Comment: The link you gave references `mutable.Map`, not `Set`. As the code also refers to `Map`, I took the liberty to update the text of your link accordingly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notice that there is already a separate overloaded method with a single parameter:

```
abstract def -=(key: A): Map.this.type
```

So the *two more more parameters* constraint is to avoid ambiguous calls. The reason for a separate method with a single parameter may be efficiency. Note that calling a variable argument method involves creating an array in the background, which would be wasted if there is only a single element to remove.

As the single-argument version of the method is abstract while the multiple-argument version is concrete, I would not be surprised if the implementation of the latter actually called the former in (a functional equivalent of) a loop. (Update: a [quick code check](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.0/src/library/scala/collection/generic/Shrinkable.scala#L1) verified my guess, although the call is indirect via `--=` .)

Answer (score 1):

I would say because of the *two or more* condition.

With that signature, you clearly enforce at least two arguments of type `A` to be passed to the method.

If you used only `*elems`, it would mean removing 0 or more elements, which wouldn't make much sense.

The fact that you specifically have a signature for removing 2 or more, and whether it makes sense or not, is beyond the scope of this answer. Like @Péter Török said, the reason for overloading this method with one param, and two or more params may be efficiency.

Comment: "and whether it makes sense or not" is kinda what I was hoping for though. This declaration is unusual enough that I'm expecting there's a good reason for it; I'd like to know what the reasoning is.